# Why I get undefined rows when table has foreign keys?

Tags: jquery, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have SQL table with foreign keys in columns SeasonID and LangID and when I try to call that table via Web API, I get only 1 row with correct data and other rows with that same foreign key, gives "undefined".

Here is examples:

DB tables and relationships

[image]

Selection-table rows:
[image]

Here is ajax call

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'api/Selections',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, val) {

                       selection += '<tr>' +
                            "<td>" + val.ISBN + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + val.Author + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + val.BookName + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + val.Publisher + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + val.Price + "</td>" +
                            "<td><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span></a></td>" +
                            '</tr>';
                    });

                    $('#selection_table').append(selection);
```

Here is Selection controller

```
// GET: api/Selections
        public IQueryable<Selection> GetSelection()
        {
            return db.Selection;
        }
```

And this is result in my Index.html page.

[image]

If foreign key value is more than once in Selection-table, row gets "undefined".

What do I need to do to get all rows shown?
Is the problem in my relationships or is it ajax call that messes this up?
If all rows has differend SeasonID and LangID, then all rows is shown.

Comment: what happens in `'api/Selections'`?

Comment: i think your problem is in the query, not in the provided ajax

Comment: I added SelectionController so you can see what api/selection does.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.